# cmake Error and libcurl version is not provided

Tags: cmake

I'm getting following error while running cmake command and also whenever it runs fine it give error libcurl version is not available

Getting this error

```
cmake -version
cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

You can also see the image below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMKmB.png)

Comment: Is your `cmake` a 32-bit binary? whats the output of `file "$( command -v cmake )"` and  `ldd "$( command -v cmake )"`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.